# Completion Block from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to translate this completionBlock located in the viewWillAppear function in Swift:

```
KeyboardHelperCompletionBlock adjustCenterUp = ^(NSNotification *notification) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{
        self.popupVC.view.centerY = self.view.centerY - [KeyboardHelper keyboardHeight] / 2;
    }];
};
```

I have the animation part:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
            self.popupVC?.view.center.y = self.view.centerY() - KeyboardHelper.keyboardHeight()/2
        })
```

But not the adjustCenterup definition.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
let adjustCenterUp: KeyboardHelperCompletionBlock = { notification in
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
        self.popupVC?.view.center.y = self.view.centerY() - KeyboardHelper.keyboardHeight() / 2
   }
}
```

but you should probably capture `self` weakly:

```
let adjustCenterUp: KeyboardHelperCompletionBlock = { [weak self] _ in
   guard let `self` = self else { return }

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
        self.popupVC?.view.center.y = self.view.centerY() - KeyboardHelper.keyboardHeight() / 2
   }
}
```